# How can I configure Webpack to use external javascript module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, external, import-maps

I have the following situation in my Web App (not node). I'm trying to load a js module via `script` and have that accessible in the modules bundled by `Webpack`.

constants.js

```js
export default message = "Test message";
```

This is loaded as an import map (works):

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "constants": "http://localhost:3000/assets/constants.js"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Another simple module (not with Webpack) is loaded like this and can access that the `constants` module:

```html
<script src="http://localhost:3000/assets/test-import.js" type="module"></script>
```

test-import.js:

```js
import { message } from 'constants'; //from importmap

console.log(message);
```

This also works fine!

However, I would like to use this same module in my `Webpacker` bundle. I've configured is like so:

```js
module.exports = {
 externals: {
  constants: 'module constants',
 }
}
```

This does not work:

App.js

```js
import { message } from 'constants'; //from importmap

console.log(message);
```

```
caught ReferenceError: constants is not defined
```

How can I access external modules in my Webpack bundle?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`externalsType.module`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstypemodule) documentation:

> Make sure to enable [`experiments.outputModule`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/#experimentsoutputmodule) first, otherwise webpack will throw errors.

A working example:

Directory structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── dist
│   ├── constants.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── main.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── constants.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js

2 directories, 9 files
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import { message } from 'constants';

console.log(message);
```

`src/constants.js`:

```js
export const message = 'Test message';
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "constants": "./constants.js"
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    externals: {
        constants: 'module constants',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [{ from: './src/constants.js' }],
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            scriptLoading: 'module',
        }),
    ],
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "http-server ./dist"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "http-server": "^14.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset index.html 375 bytes [emitted]
asset main.js 269 bytes [emitted] [javascript module] [minimized] (name: main)
asset constants.js 36 bytes [compared for emit] [from: src/constants.js] [copied] [minimized]
runtime modules 396 bytes 2 modules
orphan modules 42 bytes [orphan] 1 module
./src/index.js + 1 modules 102 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 297 ms
```

**Output**

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "constants": "./constants.js"
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script
            type="module"
            src="main.js"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

`dist/main.js`:

```js
import * as e from 'constants';
var o = {
    d: (e, r) => {
        for (var s in r) o.o(r, s) && !o.o(e, s) && Object.defineProperty(e, s, { enumerable: !0, get: r[s] });
    },
    o: (e, o) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, o),
};
const r = ((s = { message: () => e.message }), (a = {}), o.d(a, s), a);
var s, a;
console.log(r.message);
```

**Test**

Run `npm start`  to start a HTTP server

```
> http-server ./dist

Starting up http-server, serving ./dist

http-server version: 14.1.1

http-server settings: 
CORS: disabled
Cache: 3600 seconds
Connection Timeout: 120 seconds
Directory Listings: visible
AutoIndex: visible
Serve GZIP Files: false
Serve Brotli Files: false
Default File Extension: none

Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.174.79:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Access the `dist/index.html` in the browser and check the console logs:

[image]